# Get current year of latest blog post

Tags: php

So I have the below query inside a method which grabs the 5 latest posts.

```
public function get_most_recent()
{
    return BlogPost::get([
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
    ]);
}
```

How can I grab the latest post year? I have a method where I'm grabbing the current year using date('Y'), but I want to grab the latest posts year. How would I go about doing that?

Here is the method that I have:

```
public function get_most_recent_year()
{
    $posts = $this->get_most_recent();

    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        var_dump($post);
    }
}
```

If possible, I want to aim for something like `$year = get_most_recent_year()`;

**UPDATE**:

var_dump($post) gives me the following structure:

object
- protected 'post' =>
-- object
--- private 'date' =>
----- object
------ public 'date' => string '2017-09-14 09:45:53.000000'

Comment: If the blog posts are in a database, you can use `MAX(YEAR(post_date))`, replacing `post_date` with the actual column name.

Comment: @Barmar, I've updated the post with more details.

Comment: Why is the date a string instead of a `DateTime` object or a numeric timestamp?

Comment: @Barmar, it's shown as this: `public 'date' => string '2017-09-14 09:45:53.000000'` (This isn't code that I wrote, i'm just trying to decypher it - So apologies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the date and get the year from it.

```
public function get_most_recent_year()
{
    $posts = $this->get_most_recent();
    if (empty($posts)) {
        return 0;
    }
    $post = $posts[0];
    $year = $post[0]->post->date->format('Y');
    return $year;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Barmar, I'm getting a 'Unexpected property' error when parsing $post->date->date .. is it $post['date']?

Comment: The `var_dump` says that `$post` is an object, not an array. It says that `$post` has a private property named `date`, and that has a public property named `date`. I assumed that this code is in the same class as `$post` so it can access the private property.

Comment: I just noticed that there's another property called `post`, so maybe it should be `$post->post->date->date`. These are your classes, you should know how to access the data in them, I'm just guessing.

Comment: So I've gotten this portion `$posts = $this->get_most_recent();
        if (empty($posts)) {
            return 0;
        }
        var_dump($posts[0]->post);`

I've tried $post->post->date->date but that wasn't successful sadly. I then need to access `private 'date => object[DateTime] public 'date' => string '2017-09-14 09:45:53.000000'` after $posts[0]->post

Comment: Ah, so it *is* a `DateTime` object. I've updated the answer to use the `DateTime::format` method.

Comment: Sorry I should have included that, that worked! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: If you had posted the actual `var_dump` output instead of trying to simplify it, this would have been much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using WordPress. You can use `get_the_date()` to get post's date. The first parameter is PHP date format:

```
$post_year = get_the_date('Y', $latest_post_id);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update @Cade, I've updated the post with a var_dump

Comment: Do the post object return the post ID?

Answer (score 0):

To get time you can use following statement.
just simply parse the date

`<?php $time = date("Y", strtotime($row['PostDate'])); ?>`